# Probability questions with two boxes and colored balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Two boxes:

Box $A$: $5$ red balls and $3$ white balls,

Box $B$: $1$ red ball and $2$ white balls.

A fair dice is tossed. If the outcome is $3$ or $6$ then you draw a ball from box $A$ and you put it in box $B$, then a ball is drawn from box $B$. If the outcome is NOT $3$ or $6$, you draw a ball from box $B$ and you put it in box $A$, then you draw a ball from box $A$.

a. What is the probability that both balls are red?

b. If both balls are red, what is the probability that the outcome was $3$ or $6$?

My solution to a: (here box $A=U1$, and box $B=U2$)

$$P(R1\cap R2)=P(R2\,|\,R1)P(R1),$$

$$
\begin{align*}P(R1)&=P(R1\cap U1)+P(R1\cap U2)
P(R1)\\
&=P(R1\,|\,U1)P(U1)+P(R1\,|\,U2)P(U2)\\
&=\frac{5}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3}\\
&= \frac{31}{72}.
\end{align*}
$$

But I don't know how to compute $P(R2\,|\,R1)$.
Also, I don't know how to compute b.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you solve it using conditional probability, please?

Comment: Welcome! For some basic information about writing math on MSE, see 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is your definition of $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively ?

Comment: In your answer to the first question, if a red ball has been selected from box A, it is transferred to Box B, giving you two red balls and two white balls in Box B.